# Factorization polynomial over finite field

Tags: factoring

I want to factorize this polynomial over finite field $F_q$. with $q \equiv 5$ (mod 6), and $q=11$

$$x^4+ x^3 (u+u^{-1}) \rho^{-1} + x^3 (u+u^{-1}) \rho + x^2 \rho^2 + x^2 \rho^{-2} + (u+u^{-1})^2 x^2 + (u+u^{-1}) x \rho^{-1} + (u+u^{-1}) x \rho +1.$$

I know that we can use the formula $ (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$, and then we have

$$a+c = (u+u^{-1}) \rho^{-1} + (u+u^{-1}) \rho $$
$$b+d+ac = \rho^2 + \rho^{-2} + (u+u^{-1})^2$$
$$ad + bc = (u+u^{-1}) \rho^{-1} + (u+u^{-1})  \rho +1$$

then we have $a+c = ad +bc $
I am trying to solve that as $a+c-ad-bc=0$
then If $d=1$, we have 
$$a+c-a -bc =0$$
$$c-bc=0$$
either $c=0$ or $b=1 $

so I am not sure if I am in the correct way or not. I need to know how to factorize this polynomial to be irreducible over finite field

Thanks..

Comment: Is there a typo? You write $q \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ and $q = 11$ but $11 \equiv 5 \bmod 6$.

Comment: ooh yes you are right it is a mistake.. q \equiv 5 (mod 6)

Comment: I think you should edit the question to fix it.

Comment: Is there more context to the problem? I mean, is there something you need to prove which is implied by the irreducibility of that polynomial?